# Just getting the title of a post with Simple_html_dom

Tags: php

Currently I am scraping a website which has this content displayed.

```
<h2 class="entry-title">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Song Artist - Song Name</a>
</h2>
```

Now if I use the code provided below it will pull what's shown above but I want to get just the portion that is as the *Song Artist - Song Name* without the `<a href=""></a>` or `<h2></h2>` tags.

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.example.com");
    foreach ($html->find('h2[class="entry-title"]') as $data)
{
    echo $data; 
};
```

Comment: What gets echoed atm?

Comment: @thelastshadow the first portion is what's being echo'd at the moment as that's the class that I am telling it to pull from - but I just want to get the title make sense?

Comment: Does `echo $data->children(0)->innertext` work?

Comment: @thelastshadow thank you very much!

Comment: If answer helps you then you must accept that dear @Slacks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging through their pretty ancient [docs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm):

```
echo $data->children(0)->innertext
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($html->find('h2[class="entry-title"] a') as $data)
{
    echo $data->innertext; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@krishna Gupta

```
echo $data->innertext;
```

this will result with something like

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Song Artist - Song Name</a>
```

@Slacks

Just use

```
echo $data->plaintext;
```

Comment: right Krishna ! you have used the <a> tag at the end of the selector, sorry. Anyway imagine <a> tag contains any other html tag instead of select all possible children isn't better and straight forward to catch the $var->plaintext from the parent tag selector "h2[class="entry-title"]" without carring of possible childs

Comment: To select a specified tag from multiple you can use $data->children(n)->innertext ;  Where n is the position of that specified tag from multiple